# In iOS Tracking, does Firebase receive data about a first_open event if an iPhone users chose "Do Not Track"?

Tags: ios, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Non-technical here, just learning Google Analytics and recently dwelling with app analytics for a client, where their developers didn't seem very skilled in Firebase and can't help me understand this issue - can you help?

I'm trying to understand how many raw downloads in Play Console and App Store Connect are actually users that launch the app, by looking at the first_open event. However, I'm aware that iOS users get a pop-up asking if they allow tracking (or maybe another pop-up similar?).

---> **Question:** If they **do not allow tracking** on this pop-up, would our Firebase still get data about these users launching the app? What about other events that were set-up with Firebase, such as initiating a booking?

*PS: Also, now that you're here: App Store Connect is displaying 23 Total downloads (counting re-installs) for a given month in Country A, but Firebase is displaying 49 first_open events for the same country in the exact same month! How's this even possible, if a first_open only fires at least once per install, or doesn't even fire if the user never opens?*